# Changing an individual Widget's property in Grid View

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a grid view that maps data coming from a database and every Container inside it has a flat button button that says apply and i want the color of the button to change when the user clicks it it doesn't have to the be button that they press if tapping on the container also changes the buttons color that's even better [image: See the image here to understand more]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class FoundCourses extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoundCoursesState createState() => _FoundCoursesState();
}
class _FoundCoursesState extends State<FoundCourses> {
 // bool _applied = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate:
          new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  // What do i do here?
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 350,
                  width: 170,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // border: Border.all(color: Color(0xff940D5A)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17.0),
                    boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        offset: Offset(1.0, 15.0),
                        blurRadius: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 20.0, right: 10.0, left: 30.0, bottom: 3.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "$index",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff00315C),
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Instructor \nMahfuz A.",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xff00315C),
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {//or what do i here},
                          color: Color(0xff940D5A),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 65.0),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(17),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(17))),
                          child: Text(
                            "Apply",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Eimen, one way would be to generate a list of selected index in your existing code and apply the color only for selected item index. Here is how you can implement this,

```
class FoundCourses extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoundCoursesState createState() => _FoundCoursesState();
}

class _FoundCoursesState extends State<FoundCourses> {
  // bool _applied = false;
  List<int> selectedIndexList = new List<int>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home:GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate:
          new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  // What do i do here?
                  if (!selectedIndexList.contains(index)) {
                    selectedIndexList.add(index);
                  } else {
                    selectedIndexList.remove(index);
                  }
                  setState(() {

                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 350,
                  width: 170,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // border: Border.all(color: Color(0xff940D5A)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17.0),
                    boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        offset: Offset(1.0, 15.0),
                        blurRadius: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 20.0, right: 10.0, left: 30.0, bottom: 3.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "$index",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff00315C),
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Instructor \nMahfuz A.",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xff00315C),
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (!selectedIndexList.contains(index)) {
                              selectedIndexList.add(index);
                            } else {
                              selectedIndexList.remove(index);
                            }
                            setState(() {

                            });
                          }, //or what do i here},
                          color: selectedIndexList.contains(index) ? Colors.green : Color(0xff940D5A),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 65.0),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(17),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(17))),
                          child: selectedIndexList.contains(index) ? Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.white, size: 35.0,) : Text(
                            "Apply",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    )
    );
  }
}
```

[image: demo]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you it helps

Comment: Great, you're welcome. Please feel free to mark it as answer to help others with similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options, but here is what I would do: Make each *tile* stateful (instead of the whole grid) and have each tile track whether it is applied or not.

The main thing you were missing is using [setState()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) to make state changes on taps. You'll also want to check the state when you build the widget to change the color/button content.

1) Create a new StatefulWidget for each item in the Gridview:

```
class FoundCourseTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final int number;

  const FoundCourseTile(this.number);

  @override
  _FoundCourseTileState createState() => _FoundCourseTileState();
}

class _FoundCourseTileState extends State<FoundCourseTile> {
  bool applied = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                // toggle state on tap
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() => applied = !applied); 
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 350,
                  width: 170,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // border: Border.all(color: Color(0xff940D5A)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17.0),
                    boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        offset: Offset(1.0, 15.0),
                        blurRadius: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 20.0, right: 10.0, left: 30.0, bottom: 3.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "${widget.number}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xff00315C),
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Instructor \nMahfuz A.",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xff00315C),
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: FlatButton(
                          // toggle state on tap
                          onPressed: () {setState(() => applied = !applied);},
                          // set color based on state
                          color: applied ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 65.0),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(17),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(17))),
                          child: applied ? /* icon code goes here */ : Text(
                            "Apply",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Then simplify your GridView to be stateless:

```
class FoundCourses extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate:
          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => FoundCourseTile(index),
    );
  }
}
```